# jQuery - DomReady event for dynamically added elements

Tags: jquery, dom

I'm loading HTML content dynamically, specifically a  element. Due to the large number of options, all options are transferred to the clients once in a JSON array, and should then be populated by the clients' browser.
For this, I'd like to attach an event to all `<select>` elements, which creates a bunch of `<option>` elements and selects one of them based on a criteria from the `<select>` element.

This [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LXVhu/1) shows how I can achieve what I want by clicking the select element. However, I'd like to create the option tags and show the selected Index once the element is DOMReady - but I can't find an event that applies to that.

Comment: this is a bit of a blind shot, but how about the [**load event**](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/)?

Comment: I tried that, didn't work unfortunately..

Comment: do you mean `select.append(option).change(function() { var selectedIndex = $(this).children(':selected').index() });` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find a way by manually calling the event I'm binding to when adding the elements:

```
// Instead of having to "click" the select fields
// I'd like to populate the <option> tags everytime a new select item is injected into the DOM.
$(document).on("click", "select.countrylist", function() {
    var select = $(this);
    $(countries).each(function(i) {
        var option = $("<option></option>").attr("value", this.Key).text(this.Value.EnglishName);
        if (this.Key === select.data('selected')) option.prop("selected", true);
        select.append(option);
        select.get().selectedIndex = i;
    });
});
// populate all existing selects
$("select.countrylist").click();

// create new select and populate it
$('#test').click(function() {
    var x = $('<select data-selected="USA" class="countrylist"></select>').appendTo("body");
    // manually trigger a click which causes populating of select
    x.click();
});
```

[See this JSFiddle for a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/LXVhu/3/)

Note you still need to bind the click event to $(document), and not to the select itself (it will not work).

Thanks for all help!

Answer (score 1):

You could do this instead :

http://jsfiddle.net/LXVhu/2/

Store the element you just appended to the dom in a variable, then call a function populating them with this variable.

```
function populateSelect(elmt) {
var select = elmt;
    $(countries).each(function(i) {
        var option = $("<option></option>").attr("value", this.Key).text(this.Value.EnglishName);
        if (this.Key === select.data('selected')) option.prop("selected", true);
        select.append(option);
        select.get().selectedIndex = i;
    });    
}

$('#test').click(function() {
    // this select field will not be populated!
    var elmt = $('<select data-selected="USA" class="countrylist"></select>').appendTo("body");
    populateSelect(elmt);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Change your click handler as follows.

$('#test').click(function() {
        // this select field will not be populated!
        var select = $('<select data-selected="USA" class="countrylist"></select>').appendTo("body");


        $(countries).each(function(i) {
            var option = $("<option></option>").attr("value", this.Key).text(this.Value.EnglishName);
            if (this.Key === select.data('selected')) option.prop("selected", true);
            select.append(option);
            select.get().selectedIndex = i;
        });
    });
```

Comment: That doubles the code, which is what I want to avoid in the first place.